# Cannot run QjackCtl on ubuntu 16.0.4 for MIDI keyboard (QXcbConnection error)

Tags: midi

I'm trying to set up a MIDI keyboard to run on a AWS Ubuntu 16.0.4.

When I run  `qjackctl`:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm using a SSH connection from windows local (Putty).

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: So you want to connect a MIDI keyboard to the cloud server? How do you get access to Amazon's data center?

Comment: a  virtual keyboard tool in a remote box

Answer (score 0):

`qjckctl` wants to show a GUI on your computer, so you need an X server. Linux systems have one built in, but on Windows, you need to install a separate one (e.g., [Xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/)). And you have to enable X11 forwarding in your SSH configuration.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Given the fact I'm running qjacktl in the remote Ubuntu, shouldn't the solution be installing the X server on that Ubuntu box instead of my local Win?

Comment: reason I say this, I just installed Xming in my local Win10 and got the same result running: ~$ qjackctl
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: The X server displays the GUI, so it has to run on the client. You have to configure PuTTY to allow the X client on the Ubuntu server to access the X server on the Windows client.